# Memory management (segmentation and paging) in 80286 and 80386: How does it work?

Tags: memory-management, protected-mode

I found lots of Web sites and books explaining how memory management worked on the 8086 and later x86 CPUs in Real Mode. I understand, I think, how two 16 bit values, segment address and offset are combined to get a linear 20 bit physical address (shift segment four bits to the left, add offset; segments are 64K and start every 16 bytes).

But I couldn't find any good Web sites or books that explained how memory management works in Protected Mode, specifically the differences between 80286 and 80386.

Can anyone point me to a good Web site or book (or explain it right here)?

(For extra credit, i.e. an upvote, how does it work in Long Mode?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.ddj.com/184409207 Dr Dobbs ran a few articles back in 93 & 94 on this and there is not too many differences between the way the 286 and 386 handles the memory.  The basics is you can't do the manipulation on the segment:offset registers because the base memory location and length is now part of the selector which you refer to like a handle.

You set up the selector N with a base address X with a length of M.  When that selector is activated (remember the CS: assembly syntax?) that range of memory is used (paged in, etc).  Selector N (the 16bit handle) refers to that data structure.

Flat memory model [protected mode](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Memory/M77_0240_protected_diagram.htm) set the code, data and stack to the same memory addresses (and length of 4gb).  That link covers the basics pretty well.

Comment: The linked article is really good.

Answer (score 1):

For real mode, there is no memory managememt, its just multiply the segment register by 16
and adding the offset then puts this the 21bit result(yes 21bit because 0xFFFF*0x10+0xFFFF=0xFFFF0*0xFFFF=0x1FFFEF or 1_1111_1111_1111_1110_1111b, a 21bit value)
on the address buss.

For long mode, segmentation exists, but the descriptors have base 0 and limit 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF(16EB) thus its flat mode, paging is around and its like PAE paging but the Page Directory Pointer Table is extended from 4 entries to 512 entries and a Page Level 4 Table with 512 entries that each point to a different Page Directory Pointer Table.

And here are some sites that explain it in more detail:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode for real mode and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_mode for ling mode